# Match keys with regex in jq

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, json, jq

I'm writing a script that analyses JSON input (`jsonfile`):

```
  {
   "key11":1010,"key11_yes":13,"key11_no":14,
   "key12":12120,"key12_yes":9,"key12_no":25,
   "key13":12103,"key13_yes":13,"key13_no":20
  }
```

I want to use `jq tools`, and check the values of `key11`, `key12`, `key13` 
like this:

```
cat jsonfile | jq 'key[1-9][1-9]'
```

I want the pattern to work like `grep`-style regex:

```
cat jsonfile | grep 'key[1-9][1-9]'
```

If a matching key has the value null, then my script should `exit 0`.

Also I need to check the second parameter if `key[1-9]_[this part is null]` (ie. without appended `_yes` or `_no`), then `exit 0`.

Comment: your description is ambiguous. What does mean your *if value this keys is null*? Update your question with clear description, avoid confusing phrases

Comment: I've edited your question to explain the basic problem -- you're trying to match keys by pattern/regexp rather than with an exact string.  But I can't understand your examples, or the exact result you want, especially the bit about the "second parameter".  Please could you include some example inputs and indicate which ones should reach `exit 0`?

Comment: Please don't overwork your cats - just open the file directly to stdin (i.e. `<jsonfile`).  Thank you; end of public service announcement.

Comment: I want to check do this format `key11` and `key12` and `key13` exists in the json,also is the `value` of these keys `zero`?

Answer (score 25):

[`jq`'s regular expressions filters](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RegularexpressionsPCRE)  (`test`,`match`,`capture`) take raw text as their input.  To apply a regex to key names, you'll first have to convert those key names into text.

`jq` provides a function [`to_entries`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries) for that:

```
cat jsonfile | jq 'to_entries'
```

output:

```
[
  {
    "key": "key11",
    "value": 1010
  },
  {
    "key": "key11_yes",
    "value": 13
  },
  {
    "key": "key11_no",
    "value": 14
  },
  {
    "key": "key12",
    "value": 12120
  },
...
]
```

This can then feed into a filter that extracts the key, tests it against a regexp, then either outputs the whole entry or omits it:

```
if (.key|test("key[0-9][0-9]$")) then ( {key: .key, value: .value } ) else empty end
```

The matching `from_entries` function can convert the remaining entries back to their original form, or `with_entries` can do it all in one step:

```
cat jsonfile|jq 'with_entries(if (.key|test("key[0-9][0-9]$")) then ( {key: .key, value: .value } ) else empty end )'
```

The result is all the pairs from the input whose keys matched the pattern:

```
{
  "key11": 1010,
  "key12": 12120,
  "key13": 12103
}
```

Comment: thanks, @JigglyNaga, how to check value these keys are zero?
if `key11` or `key12` or `key13` value is `0` I get to know.

Comment: @pyramid13 Are you looking for zero (`0`) or null, as you originally asked?  Either way, `grep` should be able to match it.  Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/443884/edit) to show the exact input you're trying to match, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: My question has changed :) . please look this link 
[qustion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444915/process-json-format-with-jq-tools) . thanks @JigglyNaga.