# process JSON format with JQ tools

Tags: bash, shell-script, json, jq

I want check `format keys` in `bash script`. In my `json` if any `keys match` this format `key[0-9][0-9]_$` my script exit 1 else exit 2. I want use JQ tools.

Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

json=$(cat <<EOF
{"key11":12120,"key11_":13,"key11_yes":12107,
"key12":13492,"key12_no":9,"key12_yes":13483,
"key13":1345,"key13_no":9,"key13_yes":10191
}
EOF
)
```

I use this method :

```
echo "$json" | jq -e 'with_entries(if (.key|test("key[0-9][0-9]_$")) then 
({key: .key}) else empty end )'
```

And the result is :

```
{
  "key11_": null
}
```

I do not want it. I want if this key matches my script exit 1 else exit 0.

Comment: That's not JSON; JSON doesn't include variable assignments.

Comment: @ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, edit qustion :) .

Comment: Haven't I seen this question before? No, `jq` doesn't support regular expressions for "keys" (field names). You'll have to write out each "key" explicitely. Or use a list instead of numbering your keys (which may be better in the first place).

Comment: @dirkt, of course `jq`  support regular expressions for `keys`. 
please look this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443884/match-keys-with-regex-in-jq/443927?noredirect=1#comment806282_443927)

Comment: You can store the keys in an array and then check if they match , then exit with 1 or 2 status code
`mapfile -t arr < <( echo $json | jq -r 'keys[]');  
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do if [[ $i =~ ^key[1-9][1-9](_yes|_no)? ]]; then exit 1; else exit 2; fi ; done`

Comment: No, it doesn't support regular expressions for **JSON keys**. It supports regular expressions for **JSON values**.  Which is why your link has a suggestion to convert your `"key11":12120` into `{"key":"11", "value":12120}` etc. Now `11` is a **value**, and you can match on it. That amounts to the same thing I said: Fix the representation of your JSON. As you didn't actually explain what data you want to represent, this is likely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): You think you need `key11`, `key11_`, and `key11_yes`, but you don't.

Comment: `j=$( echo $json | jq -r 'keys[]');for i in "$j" do if [ \`echo "$i" | grep "^key[1-9][1-9]_$"\` ]  then   exit 1  else  exit 2  fi done
`
@Arushix, thanks a lot.

Comment: I gave a reopen vote, but please take more effort into the writing quality next time. You have already 4 reopen votes, after the fifth you will win.